# How to wait for another epic who listens to same action stream

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

So in my struggles to master RXjs, I ran into the following situation; when the application rehydrates (bootstrapped the first time), I dispatch a corresponding `REHYDRATE` action. I have two epics listening to this action, but I want the second epic only to be invoked when the first epic finishes. My current attempt looks like the following;

```
export const rehydrateEpic = (
  action$: ActionsObservable
) =>
  action$.ofType(REHYDRATE)
    .switchMap(() => {
      // Wait for the JWT token to be successfully fetched.
      return action$.ofType(GET_JWT_SUCCESS)
        // When this line is removed, you will disappear in a spacetime continuum.
        .take(1)
        .do(action => {
          // I get the action here...
          console.log(action)
        })
        .switchMap(action => {
          return action$.ofType([
              actions.GET_ACCOUNT_INFO_SUCCESS,
              actions.GET_ACCOUNT_INFO_FAILURE,
            ])
            .do(action => {
              // ...but this one is never reached :(
              console.log(action)
            })
            .startWith(actions.getAccountInfo())
        })
    })
```

I see in my devtools that I get a `GET_ACCOUNT_INFO_FAILURE` so somehow the Redux flow seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out myself. By using `zip()`, I can wait for both streams to emit. In my case within the example, it will look like this;

```
export const rehydrateEpic = (
  action$: ActionsObservable
) =>
  action$.ofType(REHYDRATE)
    // Wait for the JWT token to be successfully fetched.
    .zip(() => action$.ofType(GET_JWT_SUCCESS))
    .switchMap(() => {
      return action$.ofType([
          actions.GET_ACCOUNT_INFO_SUCCESS,
          actions.GET_ACCOUNT_INFO_FAILURE,
        ])
        .do(action => {
          // ...but this one is never reached :(
          console.log(action)
        })
        .startWith(actions.getAccountInfo())
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have two epics listening to this action, but I want the second epic only to be invoked when the first epic finishes.

Sounds like the second epic shouldn't listen for `REHYDRATE` but instead listen for an action that the first epic emits when its done. How does that sound?

Comment: That could be indeed a solution, but I would like to respond to both actions as `GET_JWT_SUCCESS` could be dispatched in other states of the application.

Maybe it is good to say that I am able to dispatch the `actions.getAccountInfo()`, the `GET_ACCOUNT_INFO_SUCCESS` also shows up in the Redux logger. But the `do()` is never called.